# XML_PARSE_HUGE on function simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, libxml2

The constant `XML_PARSE_HUGE` can be passed as the third argument to [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php). According to to [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) this flag:

> relaxes any hardcoded limit from the parser.

What is the "default hardcoded limit from the parser"?

I think relaxes is a little bit ambiguous also. Does it eliminate or increase "the hardcoded limit"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://bugs.php.net/49660:

> Since version 2.7.3 libxml limits the
>   maximum size of a single text node to
>   10MB. The limit can be removed with a
>   new option, XML_PARSE_HUGE. PHP has no
>   way to specify this option to libxml.

So I imagine this flag is the way that PHP now has to specify this option.

Answer (score 4):

time has moved:
http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

> **LIBXML_PARSEHUGE** - Sets XML_PARSE_HUGE flag, which relaxes any
>   hardcoded limit from the parser. This affects limits like maximum
>   depth of a document or the entity recursion, as well as limits of the
>   size of text nodes.
>   *Only available in Libxml >= 2.7.0 (as of PHP >=*
>   *5.3.2 and PHP >= 5.2.12)*

```
//example of use
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML( $xml , LIBXML_PARSEHUGE );
```