# PHP XMLReader failing with huge input lookup error

Tags: php, xmlreader

Suddenly, my code that has been working well started returning this error
Message:

```
XMLReader::read(): compress.zlib://file.gz:2: parser error : internal error: Huge input lookup
```

This is happening on a cpanel server, but when I run it on my localhost, it runs properly.

I tried raising the memory limit on the server.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried `XML_PARSE_HUGE`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5428055/231316

Comment: I am using the XMLReader library.
My code looks like this:

Comment: ini_set("memory_limit","20000M");
    $file = 'file.gz';  
 $reader = new XMLReader();
    $xmlfile = "compress.zlib://{$file}";  
    $reader->open($xmlfile);      
    
    //Read from the xml file.
    while ($reader->read())
    {
     continue; 
    }
    $reader->close();
 exit("\nLoop Completed\n");

Comment: The link shared by Chris uses simplexml_load_string() php function which can not handle large data files

Comment: The third parameter to [`open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.open.php) is `flags` to which you can pass [`LIBXML_PARSEHUGE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-parsehuge) which sets `XML_PARSE_HUGE`

Comment: You are the best Chris. This has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Following Chris Haas' advice, I modified my code to add **LIB_XML_PARSEHUGE** and it worked.
My code now looks like this:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","20000M"); 
$file = 'file.gz'; 
$reader = new XMLReader(); 
$xmlfile = "compress.zlib://{$file}"; 
$reader->open($xmlfile,null,LIBXML_PARSEHUGE); 
while ($reader->read()) 
{ 
   //My logic here 
} 
$reader->close();
```

Comment: Also, if you are on PHP 8.0 or greater, you can omit the second parameter and directly access the third parameter using a name: `$reader->open($xmlfile, flags: LIBXML_PARSEHUGE)`.